# kendo ui: how to migrate existing solution for dropdownlist

Tags: drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

The existing solution for dropdownlist:

```
<input id="countryid" name="countryid"
       data-role="dropdownlist"
       data-text-field="text"
       data-value-field="value" 
       data-bind="value: countryid"
       data-source="CountryidNameList" 
       data-auto-bind="true"
       data-bound="updateModel"
       data-value-primitive="true"/>

function updateModel(e) {
  var widget = e.sender;
  setTimeout(function() {
      widget.trigger("change");
  });
};
```

when we migrate to new version of Kendo UI 2015 (commercial version), the above solution does not work any more:

1. for form, the dropdownlist does not set the first value of the dropdownlist any more;
2. for kendo-grid (change the input, but still use the updateModel function), in edit mode: the dropdownlist is showing a loading icon (there is no error and the value is loaded in the dropdownlist while click)

anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can modify your kendo element a bit as:

```
<input id="countryid"
name="countryid"
data-text-field="text"
data-value-field="value"
data-option-label="Select Country..."
data-bind="source: CountryidNameList,value:countryid" data-role="dropdownlist"
></input>
```

and do the source binding from javascript. Have done a JSBin for your issue [here](http://jsbin.com/gifeveqeni/1/edit?html,js,output). Hope you find it useful!

Comment: thanks for your solution, but most time we wont set a "select...." item while using a form; am I right?    so the previous solution is good and should work in kendo UI framework.  If it does not work, I think **maybe it is a new bug that introduced in the new 2015 version**.

Comment: @cui: Have updated the JSBin to work with an input control..please check in case your requirement is good to go now